# I want -e to work case-sensitively on OS X. Is it possible?

Tags: macos, perl, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm developing a script that makes use of the `-e` flag, as in

```
unless (-e $fileName)
{
  ...
}
```

This works fine on OS X. Or, rather, it doesn't work correctly. I want it to be case-*sensitive*. The script is also run on a Linux machine, and the `-e` check fails--rightly!--because of case sensitivity.

I tried to do an alternate path with `open <FILEHANDLE, '$fileName')`, but it seems that that, too, is case insensitive.

Edit: Thanks to everyone who answered below. I know HFS+ is case-insensitive, but I thought I could "force" it somehow. I did end up forcing a check by doing something like:

```
opendir my($dh), $dirName or die "Couldn't open dir '$dirName'";
my @refFiles = readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

foreach $refFile (@refFiles)
{
    if ($refFile eq $refFileName)
    {
        $found = 1;
    }
}
```

The famous mantra: "It's not pretty, but it works."

Comment: Your `'$fileName'` should not use quotes at all, and if it does, it should use double quotes (unless you're perverse - like me - and precede the single quotes with a `qq'$fileName'`).  Likewise, the `<FILEHANDLE` notation is pretty funky; use the 3-argument version: `open my $fh, '<', $fileName or die "A horrid death";`.

Comment: Also, your title says 'case-sensitive' and the question says 'case-insensitive'; which did you really want?

Comment: `-e` just passes the argument to your system's `stat` call.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:  Case-_sensitivity_ is desired; i.e., the desire is to have `-e` only match if the filename operand is case-exact (which, unfortunately, cannot be done with `-e` on case-INsensitive filesystems such as OSX'); I've corrected the inconsistency in the question body.

Comment: Given that case-sensitive matching on a case-insensitive file system is required, I believe that some variant on the 'read file names from directory until a match is found or there are no names left' is the only feasible solution.  Any attempt to access the file by name will be case-insensitive (by default).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lack of case sensitivity is due to the filesystem you are using (HFS+), not the Perl functions `-e` and `open`, nor the underlying *stat(2)* and *open(2)* system calls.

The HFS+ filesystem is not case sensitive by default; however, you may elect to create a case-sensitive HFS+ volume when initializing a new filesystem (using *Disk Utility*, *diskutil*, or *newfs_hfs*, etc.): just select the “Case-sensitive” version.

I have seen reports of (badly written) programs malfunctioning when run from a case-sensitive boot volume, so I would advise you to use a separate volume for your case-sensitive work. For example, create a disk image (i.e. “sparse disk bundle image”) with a “Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)” filesystem and mount it when you need to do your case-sensitive work (e.g. `open ~/case-sensitive.sparsebundle`, then `cd /Volumes/Case-sensitive/foobar` to do your case-sensitive work from there).

Answer (score 5):

By default HFS+ is case-insensitive so -e must be as well since it uses filesystem primitives to do the check.  Having -e be case-sensitive on a case-insensitive filesystem would be perverse and evil; you could have code that confirms nonexistence of a file with -e and then have a subsequent open truncate an existing file, or have open fail because the file exists and is unreadable/unwritable.

Answer (score 2):

Using a home-built Perl (5.14.1 - I must upgrade sometime soon) on MacOS X 10.7.2, and the following script (called `x.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (@ARGV)
{
    print "OK $file\n" if (-e $file);
}
```

I invoked the command as:

```
$ perl x.pl x.pl X.pl X.PL xxx.sql
OK x.pl
OK X.pl
OK X.PL
OK xxx.sql
$
```

(I happen to have a file `xxx.sql` in my current directory.)

This is a standard MacOS X hard disk; I've not made it case-sensitive (which is, I believe, an option).

So, on the basis of my available evidence, the `-e` operator is appropriately case-insensitive in Perl on MacOS X.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers focus on explaining *why* `-e` works case-INsensitively on OSX, and why it does so for good reasons in general.

However, **sometimes you DO want to know whether a path exists in case-exact form, because even though the *filesystem* may not care, *other software* may**.

Perl itself is an example:
On OSX, Perl (unfortunately) accepts case variations of a module name with the `use` statement, because `use` performs filesystem lookups, which are inherently case-INsensitive. However, actually *using* that module will NOT work, unless the module name is case-EXACT; for instance: `perl -MData::Dumper -E 'print Dumper(666)'` (OK) vs. `perl -Mdata::dumper -E 'print Dumper(666)'` (breaks, because even though *loading* the module seemingly succeeded, its elements, such as `Dumper()`, cannot be accessed).

The problem in a nutshell: if path `/FOO/BAR` exists in your HFS+ filesystem (on OSX),
`-e '/foo/bar'` or any case variation thereof will indicate that the path exists, and there's no easy way to determine if `/foo/bar` is a case-exact representation or, more generally, what the path's true case is.

Here's a **naïve implementation** that uses the following approach:

- Takes advantage of the fact that `File::Glob::bsd_glob()` by default acts case-SENSITIVELY even on on OSX, whose filesystem (HFS+) is by default case-INsensitive.
- However, matching only occurs for path components containing an actual *pattern*, whereas *literal* names are returned as-is.
- Therefore, a glob is constructed from the input path that turns *every*
  path component into a self-matching pattern, by enclosing the 1st char. of every path component in [] (a set matching only that char. itself).

```perl
sub istruecasepath {
  use File::Glob qw/bsd_glob/;
  return defined bsd_glob join '', map { 
      m`^(//?|\.|\.\.|)$` ? 
        $_ 
        : 
        '[' . substr($_, 0, 1) . ']' . substr($_, 1)
    } split m`(//?)`, shift;
}
```

This works with the following **limitations**:

- the input path must not contain non-ASCII characters
- the input path must not contain pattern metacharacters (i.e., the path components must not contain literal chars. such as `*` or `[` that could be misconstrued as pattern (globbing) chars.

Here is a **robust implementation**, which involves additional work to overcome these limitations; input is expected as a Unicode string:

```
sub istruecasepath {
  use File::Glob qw/:bsd_glob/;
  use Unicode::Normalize;
  # Convert to NFD Unicode normal form, because that's how HFS+ stores names.
  my $path_nfd_quoted = NFD shift;
  # \-quote glob characters and '\' instances.
  $path_nfd_quoted =~ s/[][{}*?\\]/\\$&/;                                                   # /
  my $glob = join '', map { 
      m`^(//?|\.|\.\.|)$` ? 
        $_ 
        : 
        do { my $len = m`^\\` ? 2 : 1; '[' . substr($_, 0, $len) . ']' . substr($_, $len) } 
    } split m`(//?)`, $path_nfd_quoted;
  return defined bsd_glob "$glob", GLOB_QUOTE;
}
```

---

As a bonus, here's **a variant that *returns* the case-exact path as stored in the filesystem**, given a case variation:

```
sub getruecasepath {
  use File::Glob qw/:bsd_glob/;
  use Unicode::Normalize;
  # Convert to NFD Unicode normal form, because that's how HFS+ stores names.
  my $path_nfd_quoted = NFD shift;
  # \-quote glob characters and '\' instances.
  $path_nfd_quoted =~ s/[][{}*?\\]/\\$&/;                                                   # /
  my $glob = join '', map { 
      m`^(//?|\.|\.\.|)$` ? 
        $_ 
        : 
        do { my $len = m`^\\` ? 2 : 1; '[' . substr($_, 0, $len) . ']' . substr($_, $len) } 
    } split m`(//?)`, $path_nfd_quoted;
  my $path_truecase = bsd_glob "$glob", GLOB_NOCASE | GLOB_QUOTE;
  return if not defined $path_truecase;
  # !! bsd_glob() returns a raw UTF8-encoded byte sequence that isn't
  # !! automatically reconverted to a Unicode string, so we must do it 
  # !! manually here.
  utf8::decode($path_truecase);
  return $path_truecase;
}
```